# App crashed on app store, not in local version

Tags: iphone, objective-c, app-store

I ran into a horrifying bug when my app went live. It crashes in a spot where it had been fine.

1. download from app store using complimentary review code
2. start app
3. press start button
4. CRASH

NOTE: crash reoccurs at every app startup until phone is rebooted - then it disappears

When I try to replicate without the app store

1. start app
2. press start button
3. everything is good.

....

I immediately pulled the app from sale.  Right now, I can't replicate at all because I can't download the app.

How to debug?

Comment: If it was fine after a reboot, I would probably say that your device was low on memory and that the app could not claim all it needed.

Comment: my memory (I was rushing through this test when I saw the problem) is I could replicate after reboot/reload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Download the app from the store onto your device.
2. Gather the crash reports off of the device [manually](http://www.anoshkin.net/blog/2008/09/09/iphone-crash-logs/) (
3. Run them through [symbolicatecrash](http://code.coneybeare.net/fixing-symbolicatecrash) (you did keep the dsym's right?)
4. Find error, rinse and repeat.

Comment: Is there any way to get the app from the store without going live?

Comment: No. but you mentioned that you had already done that and was getting a crash.  The crash report is still on your device.

Comment: @BankStrong You can access the crash reports by plugging your iPhone into your computer and viewing the Crash Reports tab in Xcode's Organiser. Assuming you've kept the dSYM files along with the build of the App you released (and since pulled), you should be able to get a fully symbolicated crash report.